# Codeception Laravel5 Module Cleanup

Tags: laravel-5.1, codeception

I have been using Codeception `2.1.2` with the `Db` module to test my Laravel `5.1.35` project for a while, using the `Db` module to handle database cleanup between tests. Because I have a significant amount of data setup that needs to occur, as the test suite has grown my tests have slowed down significantly.

I have recently upgraded to Codeception `2.2.6` and all tests work as I would expect. When I then remove the `Db` Module in favor of the `Laravel5` module, tests run faster but get gradually slower and slower over the duration of the suite, where tests that take a second or two in isolation, may take upwards of minutes to complete when running the full suite.

It seems like there's a memory leak somewhere, either in my code or in the Laravel5 module itself, but it is incredibly difficult to pinpoint. I've tried removed all `DB` transactions in code to see if nested transactions were the cause, different versions of Codeception, different cleanup methods, like not using `Laravel5` to clean up, but rather using a `Seeder` to clean up transactional data but have had no luck.

Any ideas or thoughts would be greatly appreciated.